# hpple html parse block by block or property by property?

Tags: iphone, xpath, hpple

I'm new about hpple and xpath. for the below html code,I want to get both "title" and "tag" information.

From hpple's example code, I can get a array of  title, and another array of  tag. But if there are six properties I'm interested, there will be six arrays.

can I find the div[class="entry"], then get its child's , div[class="meta"]? (can anybody share the code?)

Thanks.

```
<div class="content">

<div id="1" class="entry">
  <h2 class="title"> title for  entry 1 </h2>
 <div class="meta"> tag:xxx </div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="entry">
  <h2 class="title"> title for  entry 2 </h2>
 <div class="meta"> tag:xxx </div>
</div>

...

</div>
```

Comment: Array is not an XPath data type. Please consired to rephrase this question in order to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

```
@"//div[@class='content']//div[@class='entry']//div[@class='meta']"
```

This returns tag:xxx for both entries.

Answer (score 0):

> **I want to get both "title" and "tag" information**

```
//div[@class='content']/div[@class='entry']/*[@class='meta' or @class=title"']
```

This XPath gets all tags with **class title or meta** children of **div class entry** child of any **div class content**.